# Discord.py bot won't connect to a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make some basic music commands with my discord bot, but I can't seem to get the bot to connect to the vc. Here's the code I have tried:

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def join(self, ctx):
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if channel: 
            print(channel.id)
            await channel.connect(reconnect=True) 
        else:
            await ctx.send('bruh you arent in a vc')
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working? Also, here are my imports, in case they are the problem (for whatever reason):

```
import asyncio
import youtube_dl
import shutil
import ffmpeg 
import os
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import datetime
```

If anyone knows the problem, and how I could fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Any errors being thrown? Does the bot have necessary permissions to join the VC? Is it able to *see* the VC?

Comment: No errors, and the bot has permissions

Comment: Do you have a custom error handler that might be swallowing the error?

Comment: Nope, no custom error handler or anything. I tried to remove all unnecessary imports, but that didn't work either.

Comment: The cog that it's in, is it actually loaded? Is it sending the `bruh you aren't in a vc` if you're not connected to a vc? Does it print the channel ID?

Comment: It prints the channel id, but does nothing else

Comment: If you add another print statement after the `await channel.connect(...`, does it print anything out? If it doesn't then I suspect that you maybe have an `on_command_error` somewhere that's being forgotten about

Comment: Doesn't print anything, but I don't see why an ArgumentError and CooldownError checker would do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215726/discussion-between-diggy-and-oblique).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install: `pip install discord.py[voice]`

Maybe you have this problem: `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice`

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT:**
Full Solution:

```
@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if channel:
        print(channel.id)
        await channel.connect(reconnect=False)
    else:
        await ctx.send('bruh you arent in a vc')
```

quick fix

**change**

```
async def join(self, ctx):
```

**TO:**

```
async def join(ctx):
```

Comment: Now I get 'discord.errors.ClientException: Callback for join command is missing "ctx" parameter.'